# How to specify two Allowed Paths in HandleHTTPProcessor in Apache NiFi

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I want to specify two Allowed Paths in NiFi Handle HTTP Processor properties but could not able to figure out how to do it.

Example -
URL - localhost:8444/test1_flow and localhost:8444/test2_flow
Allowed paths would be - test1_flow , test2_fow

here in the above example , I need to keep same port but Paths will be different. Can someone please guide me.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.16.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HandleHttpRequest/index.html

Allowed Paths - A Regular Expression that specifies the valid HTTP Paths that are allowed in the incoming URL Requests.

so, regular expression could look like this:

```
Allowed Paths:  test1_flow|test2_flow
```